# Handling Datacontext Operations in Timer_Elapsed using StructureMap

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, structuremap, datacontext

Please what is the best way to wire up/use a datacontext object in a timer_elapsed event. I have a datacontext object within a timer_elapsed that runs perfectly the first time but does nothing on subsequent calls of the timer_elapsed event. I understand a new instance is created for every call of the elapsed event on a threadpool thread. How do I control this behaviour or at least get my code to run consistently. Thanks.

This is my structure map config

```
ForRequestedType<BulkSMSDataContext>()
            .TheDefaultIs(() => new BulkSMSDataContext())
            .CacheBy(InstanceScope.Hybrid);
```

This is my timer implementation

```
void _timerSendScheduledMessages_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime currentUTC = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(-DateTime.UtcNow.Second).AddMilliseconds(-DateTime.UtcNow.Millisecond);

        var msgToSend = from c in _messageRepository.GetMessages(MessageTypes.Scheduled)
                        where c.Time == currentUTC
                        select c;


        foreach (var msg in msgToSend)
        {
            int scheduledMsgID = msg.MessageID;
            Response res = _messageService.Send(msg);
            _messageRepository.DeleteScheduledMessage(scheduledMsgID);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To better control the scope I would change the elapsed event to create a new _messageRepository each time it's called, assuming you pass the datacontext to the _messageRepository that is. Then let structuremap inject your datacontext into it.

Otherwise you end up with a poorly defined unit of work which tends to bring up scoping issues like the one you are having.

Without seeing you implementation though, hard to tell exactly.